# how to extract two strings from each line

Tags: awk

I have a file of the following content:

```
product a1 version a2 owner a3
owner b1 version b2 product b3 size b4
....
```

I am interested in extracting product and version from each line using a shell script, and write them in 2 columns with product first and version second.  So the output should be:

```
a1 a2
b3 b2
...
```

I used "while read line", but it is extremely slow.  I tried to use awk, but couldn't figure out how to do it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The format of your file is very weird: so the values are not in fixed columns (you can start with "owner", then "version but you can also start with "product"?)?

Comment: Most of these solutions are requiring that each "a\*" and "b\*" is a single word. Does the sample data you've shown actually represent the data you have?

Comment: If you had a working solution with "while read line", but it was too slow, then rather than abandoning that approach, post a new question with that working solution and ask how to speed it up.

Answer (score 4):

The following will do what you want:

```
$ nl dat
     1  product a1 version a2 owner a3
     2  owner b1 version b2 product b3 size b4

$ awk 'NF { delete row; 
            for( i=1; i <= NF; i += 2 ) {
                row[$i] = $(i+1)
            } 
            print( row["product"], row["version"]) 
           }' dat
a1 a2
b3 b2
```

This builds an associative array from the name-value pairs in your data file by position, and then retrieves the values by name. The `NF` in the pattern ensures blank lines are ignored. If *product* or *version* are otherwise missing, they'll likewise be missing in the output.

Answer (score 4):

A different `perl` approach:

```
perl -lane 'my %h = @F; print "$h{product} $h{version}"' input.txt
```

Uses auto-split mode to put each word of each line in an array, turns that into a hash/associative array, and prints out the keys you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perl to do that:

```
perl -lnE '
    $x=$1 if /(?=product\h+(\H+))/; 
    $y=$1 if /(?=version\h+(\H+))/;
    say "$x $y" if $x && $y;
    $x=$y="";' file
```

Or, same method with GNU awk:

```
gawk '/product/ && /version/{
    match($0,/product[ \t]+([^ \t]+)/,f1)
    match($0,/version[ \t]+([^ \t]+)/,f2)
    print f1[1],f2[1]
}' file
```

With the example, either prints:

```
a1 a2
b3 b2
```

The advantage here is only complete lines are printed where both targets are found.

Comment: With gawk you can use `\s` instead of `[ \t]` and `\S` instead of `[^ \t]`.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
          if($i=="version")v=$(i+1)
          if($i=="product")p=$(i+1)}}
       {print p,v}' data.txt
a1 a2
b3 b2
```

If you have lines without a version or product number, and you want to skip them:

```
awk '{ok=0}
     {for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
        if($i=="version"){v=$(i+1);ok++}
        if($i=="product"){p=$(i+1);ok++}}}
     ok==2{print p,v}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the quick and excellent replies.  I ended up using the awk version as it is most convenient for me to insert into an existing shell script.  But I learned a lot from other scripts too.